# How stackoverflow site pages load content dynamically?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, ajax

I am curious to know how stackoverflow or any stackexchange site loads content dynamically.

For example, When you are on a specific tag's page the questions keep on loading as they get asked. I can see there is no ajax call taking place in the network section of my browser.

I am curious to know which technology is being use in SO for loading this content dynamically.

Many thanks for those who give their time answering this question.

Comment: "in order to use this feature you must have a browser that supports web sockets" > web sockets it is